# How to find whether a PeopleEditor control has a value or not

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint

I have to disable a button if sharepoint people editor is empty in an aspx page

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://wsstipstricks.blogspot.in/2011/06/people-editor-control-validation-for.html) blog. Very similar one to your question. Hope it will help